# need to display the header in all screen on react native navigation V5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5

i have the following header.js

```
  import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from '@expo/vector-icons';


export default function header({navigation}, title) {

    const openMenu =() => {
        navigation.openDrawer()
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name='menu' 
    size={24} color='black'
    onPress={openMenu}
    style={styles.icon}
    />
            <View style={styles.headerTitle}>
            <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/oau-ico-hat.png')}/>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>title={title}</Text>
               
                {/*  */}
                
            </View>
                  </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header:{
     width:'100%',
        height: '100%',
        flexDirection:'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'center',
        
        
    },
    headerText:{
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        color: '#333',
        letterSpacing: 1,
        marginTop:8,
        marginHorizontal: 50,
        marginLeft:10,
    },
    logo: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        
       
    },
    icon:{
        position:'absolute',
        left: 0.7,
    },
    headerTitle:{
        flexDirection:'row',
       
    },
})
```

then i had the following App.js

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const DrawerNavigator=() => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
     drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props}
     />}
     >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={StackNavigator}
     
      
      />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Faculties" component={Faculty}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabNavigator = ({navigation}) => (
  <Tab.Navigator 
  screenOptions={{
    headerStyle:{backgroundColor: "tomato" , elevation:0},
  headerTintColor:"#fff",
   headerTitleAlign:'center',
   
   headerTitle: () => <Header navigation={navigation} title='O.A.U'/>


 }}>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={DrawerNavigator} />
     <Tab.Screen name="Faculties" component={Faculty} 
     
     /> 
    </Tab.Navigator>
)


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const StackNavigator = ({navigation}) => (
  <Stack.Navigator   

  screenOptions={{
     headerStyle:{backgroundColor: "tomato" , elevation:0},
   headerTintColor:"#fff",
    headerTitleAlign:'center',
    
     headerTitle: () => <Header navigation={navigation} title='O.A.U'/>


  }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}
    options={() =>  {<Header navigation={navigation} title='O.A.U'/>}}
    
  
    />
    <Stack.Screen name="TabsBottom" component={Faculty}
   
    />
    
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

  

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header:{
   
    alignItems:'center',
},
})
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      
     <TabNavigator/>
    </NavigationContainer>  
  );
}
```

I have homeStack.js where in React Navigation V4 it was working as follow:any idea how can i make that work in V% react-navigation

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Header from '../shared/header';
import Home from '../screens/homeScreen';
import Faculty from '../screens/faculties'

const screens ={
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        screenOptions:({ navigation } )=> {
            return {
            headerTitle: () => <Header navigation={navigation} title='O.A.U'/>,
        }
        }
    },
   
    Faculty: {
        screen: Faculty,
        navigatioptions:({ navigation } )=> {
            return {
            headerTitle: () => <Header navigation={navigation} title='O.A.U'/>,
        }
        }
    }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
export default HomeStack;
```

i have a drwer.js for the drawer meny as follow:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import {
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItem,
  DrawerItemList,
} from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import {
  Avatar,
  Title,
  Caption,
  Paragraph,
  Drawer,
  Text,
  TouchableRipple,
  Switch,
} from "react-native-paper";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons, FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import Home from './homeStack'

export function DrawerContent({ ...props }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        {/* <DrawerItemList {...props}/> */}
        <DrawerItem
          icon={({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          )}
          label="Home"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
        />
        <DrawerItem
          icon={({ color, size }) => (
            <FontAwesome5 name="university" color={color} size={size} />
          )}
          label="Faculties"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Faculties")}
        />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

my questions as follow:
1.how can i display the header in all screen as the header will include the menu burger that pulls the drawer menu?
2. when clicking on Faculties menu from tab the drawer menu is not working unless i click on home menu from tab navigation, is my nested navigation correct or where am I going wrong?
P/S: please note this my first time on developing mobile app using react.
you can have a look at github and see if you can help from there @  https://github.com/sudani/Uni_app.git

Answer (score 0):

after spending the last 2 days looking for answer i found great youtube tutorial, i frogot about rules posting link but here what i have managed to do:
removed all the stack screens, tab screens to separate file then import the file into App.js:
the file as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

import HomeScreen  from './homeScreen'
import FacultyScreen  from './faculties';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
const FacultyStack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const MainTabScreen =() => (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor="#fff"
      barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'tomato' }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Faculty"
        component={FacultyStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bell" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    
    </Tab.Navigator>
)
export default MainTabScreen;
const HomeStackScreen =({navigation}) => (
    <HomeStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "tomato", elevation: 0 },
       headerTintColor: "#fff",
       headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerShown:true,
        
      }}
    >
        <HomeStack.Screen name= "Home" component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
            title:'Overview',
            headerLeft: () => (
                <Icon.Button name="ios-menu" size={26}
                backgroundColor="tomato" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer() }></Icon.Button>
            )
        }}
        />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
)

const FacultyStackScreen =({navigation}) => (
    <FacultyStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "tomato", elevation: 0 },
       headerTintColor: "#fff",
       headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerShown:true,
        
      }}
    >
        <FacultyStack.Screen name= "Faculty" component={FacultyScreen}
        options={{
            
            headerLeft: () => (
                <Icon.Button name="ios-menu" size={26}
                backgroundColor="tomato" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer() }></Icon.Button>
            )
        }}
        />
    </FacultyStack.Navigator>
)
```

then the App.js as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import MainTabScreen from './app/screens/MaintabScreen';


import { DrawerContent } from "./app/routes/drawer";


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer initialRouteName= "Home">
         
       <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
           <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={MainTabScreen}/>
           {/* <Drawer.Screen name="Faculty" component={FacultyStackScreen}/> */}
       </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
```

the drawer helper stayed the same as before

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import {
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItem,
  DrawerItemList,
} from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import {
  Avatar,
  Title,
  Caption,
  Paragraph,
  Drawer,
  Text,
  TouchableRipple,
  Switch,
} from "react-native-paper";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons, FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import Home from './homeStack'

export function DrawerContent({ ...props }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        {/* <DrawerItemList {...props}/> */}
        <DrawerItem
          icon={({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          )}
          label="Home"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
        />
        <DrawerItem
          icon={({ color, size }) => (
            <FontAwesome5 name="university" color={color} size={size} />
          )}
          label="Faculties"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Faculty")}
        />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I found this an Easy way of managing the nested navigation and it is almost what i wanted if anyone has better improvement suggestion that will be great